# What is wrong with MS SQL Server (*.sql) script backup restore operation with SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a 6GB `*.sql` script backup file, which when I'm loading into database:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U SA -d testdbb -i whole_DB_backup.sql -o result.log
```

It taking days to finish the script. On the contrary for same database `*.bak` backup file, it taking only 5 minutes to load into database server from within `SQL Server Management Studio`.
Anything going wrong behind the scene? How can I speed up `sqlcmd` restore operation?

Comment: You could try this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get a good answer here. As to why, basically it comes down to restoring a .bak-file simply replaces the data in your database while sqlcmd will make a few million inserts which needs to update indicies, check constraints etc which takes a lot of time.

Comment: Without know how your script is written, we can't offer much help. Presumably your script contains all the `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `INSERT`, etc statement you need. You might, for example, only be inserting 1 row per `INSERT` statement; a painfully slow way to insert things.

Comment: Restoring a backup file will ALWAYS be faster than running a giant script containing statements to create your schema and statement to insert all your data one row at a time.  Such are the expected results when you need to "backup" to a lower version or edition of the database engine if that is the reason for your scripting approach.

Comment: @SMor: plain SQL Script lets me explore content on terminal `vim`. On the contrary, *.BAK file lets me explore only in `ssme` .  Unfortunately, for this particular snapshot of database , I only have *.SQL Backup.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're not loading a 6G backup, you're running a 6G SQL script.  Every `INSERT`, every `CREATE TABLE`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT` etc. etc. are all going to have to be parsed by SQL Server, have a query plan generated for each statement,  and almost certainly most every SQL statement is not going to get cached--and that doesn't get into transaction overhead and other stuff that needs to be done when running SQL.

Performing a `RESTORE` on the other hand, doesn't have to deal with any of that, for the most part, except for the overhead needed to create an intact DB from the .bak.

Basically, the process will be slow, and the only way around that would be to write a script to parse the .SQL file and convert it to something you could use in BCP or something.  Just run the script and bite the bullet.